# How to send the components in whatsapp cloud api?

Tags: php, api, curl

I want to send the parameters in in whatsapp cloud api. How can I achieve that.

```
$messageData = array(
        'messaging_product' => "whatsapp",
        'to' => "123456789",
        'type' => "template",
        'template' => array("name"=> "hello_world",'language'=>array("code"=>"en_Us")),
    );
```

**I want it like this**

```
{
      type: 'template',
      messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
      to: e.recipient_number,
      template: {
        name: WHATSAPP_TEMPLATE_NAME,
        language: { code: LANGUAGE_CODE },
        components: [
          {
            type: 'body',
            parameters: [
              { type: 'text', text: e.customer_name },
              { type: 'text', text: e.item_name },
              { type: 'text', text: e.delivery_date },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    }
```

**The error I am getting**

{"error":{"message":"(#132000) Number of parameters does not match the expected number of params","type":"OAuthException","code":132000,"error_data":{"messaging_product":"whatsapp","details":"body: number of localizable_params (0) does not match the expected number of params (3)"},"error_subcode":2494073,"fbtrace_id":"Abab9mTp_dJ9Ryd4ytHPl7Y"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$messageData = array(
    'messaging_product' => "whatsapp",
    'to' => 123456789,
    'type' => "template",
    'template' => array("name"=> "random name",'language'=>array("code"=>"en_Us"),'components'=> 
       array(array(
        "type" => "body",
        "parameters" => array(array("type"=> "text","text"=> google.com),array("type"=> "text","text"=> $shopName),array("type"=> "text","text"=> 123456789)))))
);
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the **hello_world** template is a pre-defined template, created by the Whatsapp business API team. If you need to send parameters, you have to create a template with variables in its body like

URL - {{1}}

Then pass parameter like this,

```
 var data = JSON.stringify({
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
"to": number,
"type": "template",
"template": {
  "name": "template_name",
  "language": {
    "code": "language_code"
  },
  "components": [
    {
        "type": "body",
        "parameters": [{
            "type": "text",
            "text":"https://www.whatsapp.com"
        }]
    }],
}});
```

Your output message will be URL - https://www.whatsapp.com

Answer (score 1):

From "Sarkar's Answer above,

```
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "to": 123456789,
  "type": "template",
  "template": {
    "name": "random name",
    "language": {
      "code": "en_Us"
    },
    "components": [
      {
        "type": "body",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "text"
          },
          {
            "type": "text"
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": 123456789
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```