# sending message from Facebook whatsapp api to my number

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I am sending message from Facebook whatsapp api to my number for testing. Message is sent from php but not recieved on mobile. Did I must register business on facebook?

{"messaging_product":"whatsapp","contacts":[{"input":"923040165804","wa_id":"923040165804"}],"messages":[{"id":"wamid.HBgMOTIzMDQwMTY1ODA0FQIAERgSOEM3RDJDRDMyMkFENkIzMTgyAA=="}]}

this php code that I am using.

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/********/messages/',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>json_encode(array("to"=> $number, "messaging_product" => 'whatsapp', "recipient_type" => 'individual',"type"=>"text", 'text'=> array('body'=>'hello_wo332233rld','preview_url'=>'false'))),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Authorization: Bearer '.$chatApiToken,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        echo $response;
```

Comment: if you are still looking for an answer I have a sample code that works.

Comment: @RiyaSingh I'm looking for it, could you share with us how it was done

Comment: i have just answered it below...check out the post below "Here is a sample code, hope it helps. It works for me

Point to remember Mentioning a template name is mandatory. The messages are subject to the approved templates"

Comment: and yes...you will need create an app on developer.facebook.com > My Apps 

After which, click on whatsapp > Quick Start. Add a number, and you will get all your access tokens etc

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. And sending from dev console template, same issue too.
After change the phone number, it has worked. I don't know if will work at the production environment, but...

Comment: This looks like a comment, not an answer
Also the answer is bit unclear

Comment: I had the same issue, but after change the phone number, worked, so, the solution: change the phone number!

Comment: Has anyone found the solution yet? Changing the phone number isnt the solution as so far I have changed 5.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I came across the same problem and the solution was to upgrade whatsapp to the latest version on my phone. I added some [troubleshooting issues](https://github.com/ignacio-chiazzo/ruby_whatsapp_sdk#troubleshooting) to the Ruby library that could help with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code, hope it helps. It works for me

**Point to remember**
Mentioning a template name is mandatory. The messages are subject to the approved templates

```
     $number = $_GET['number']; //you can use POST, I tried GET for testing
     $template = array(
       'name'=>'hello_world', //your your own or any default template. The names and samples are listed under message templates
       'language'=>array('code'=>'en_us') //you can use yours
       );

     $endpoint = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/USE_YOUR_OWN/messages';
     $params = array('messaging_product'=>'whatsapp', 'to'=>$number, 'type'=>'template', 'from'=>'91xxxxxxxxxx', 'access_token'=>'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN','template'=>json_encode($template));

       $headers = array('Authorization'=>'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN','Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36');
       $url = $endpoint . '?' . http_build_query($params);
  //echo $params.'<br>';
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
       curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
       $result = curl_exec($ch );
       echo $result; //you can skip this, I did it to check the results
       curl_close( $ch );
```

This finally echos the result as

```
{"messaging_product":"whatsapp","contacts":[{"input":"15645446547","wa_id":"15645446547"}],"messages":[{"id":"wamid.HBgLMTU2NDU0NDY1NDcVAgARGBIwNjJEMjc3NzIzQzA2RjY2QTYA"}]}
```

And the message is getting received.

refer the following thread on how to pass a parameter AKA "passing components"

[How to send the components in whatsapp cloud api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72433645/how-to-send-the-components-in-whatsapp-cloud-api)